# How do I set random values in processing that are in certain intervals

Tags: processing

For example, I'm trying to make it so when one of the circles goes off the edge of the screen, it resets it's X-coordinates to anywhere from -100,0 or 840,940. This is because I want it to move back onto the screen from another random location.

Is there a way to use the random function in processing like this?

The only way I could think of to get around this would be doing this:

```java
//in my real program this would be taking place in a for loop parsing through an array 
int = random(1,2);
if(x = 1){
   posX[i] = random(-100,0);
}
else{
   posX[i] = random(840,940);
}
```

But this would take extra space. I assume there is some way to just create random values within a certain interval.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is basically the approach I would take. There are a few issues with your code: you're using `=` instead of `==`, and you're comparing exactly `1` instead of a range. You probably want something like this instead:

```
float x = random(1);
if(x < .5){
  myValue = random(-100, 0);
}
else{
  myValue = random(840, 940);
}
```

One cool thing about programming is that you can make your own functions, like this:

```
float getValueFromRanges(float startOne, float endOne, float startTwo, float endTwo){

  if(random(1) < .5){
    return random(startOne, endOne);
  }
  else{
    return random(startTwo, endTwo);
  }
}
```

Then you could just call this function whenever you wanted a random value from those ranges:

```
float myValue = getValueFromRanges(-100, 0, 840, 940);
```

Or you could do this in one line of code using the ternary operator:

```
float myValue = random(1) < .5 ? random(-100, 0) : random(840, 940);
```

This last approach is not very readable, so I'd probably go with creating a function.